# rxdart filter return a single item from stream

Tags: flutter, stream, rxdart

How can I filter a stream? I want to get one record where the uid matches. The return item must a be a stream.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:demo/models/profile.dart';
import 'package:demo/services/database/database.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'bloc_provider.dart';

class SearchResultsBloc implements BlocBase {
  SearchResultsBloc() {
    DatabaseService().Search().listen((data) => _inList.add(data));
  }

  final _listController = BehaviorSubject<List<Profile>>();
  Stream<List<Profile>> get outList => _listController.stream;
  Sink<List<Profile>> get _inList => _listController.sink;

  final _detailsController = BehaviorSubject<Profile>();
  
  Stream<Profile> outDetails(String uid) {
   // return single item  from outList where uid matches.
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listController.close();
    _detailsController.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
  Stream<Profile> outDetails(String uid) {
    return outList.map<Profile>((results) => 
      results.firstWhere((profile) => profile.uid == uid)
    );
  }
```

Basically, you're mapping your stream of lists of profiles to a stream of profiles, where, for each list of profiles, you're returning the first (possibly null) profile that matched the argument.

P.S. Don't forget to manage the returned stream properly on the caller side.

---

**EDIT**: if it's possible that no profile be found for a given `uid`, you should add the `orElse:` argument:

```
results.firstWhere(
  (profile) => profile.uid == uid,
  orElse: () => null
)
```

This will make sure `StateError` doesn't get thrown, in case returning null is the right thing to do for you.

Comment: `firstWhere` could throw `StateError` when `uid` not found, also i believe that returning `null` is not what OP needs - thats why i would use `expand` (or `transform`), not `map`

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much.
@pskink could you please provide code sample of your suggestions?

Now I need to create two more methods one for previous item and one for next item based on current uid, not sure how I can do that. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Huzzi what should be done if `uid` is not found by `results.firstWhere`? now it throws an exception which is not what you want?

Comment: @pskink maybe return a null or something instead of exception. I'm returning list of documents from firestore so there shouldn't be case where the uid is not found.

Comment: @pskink thanks for the pointer to the need to handle null values, I added a code example on how to handle that

Comment: It also depends on what you want to happen when no uid matches. A transform that excludes null result will just not yield anything. If you want to react and display something like `No result found`, it's easy to do by handling the `null` case.

Comment: yep, now it will not throw any exceptions

Comment: Thanks both. I created this new method to get next item in the list but it brings nothing.

 nextProfile(String uid) {
    var id = outList
        .map<int>(
            (results) => results.indexWhere((profile) => profile.uid == uid))
        .first;

    id.then((index) {
      return outList.map<Profile>((results) => results[index + 1]);
    });
  }

Comment: If one of you could answer my next question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108344/dart-filter-stream-list-using-closure