# Dart filter stream list using closure

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a list of firestore records as stream. I want to pass uid of a record to the list and return next item.

```
uid     name
-----|-------------
001  | Steve
002  | David
003  | Mark
004  | George
-------------------
```

If I pass uid **001** the method should return **002 | David** and passing 001 or 004 should return null.

```
class SearchResultsBloc implements BlocBase {
  SearchResultsBloc() {
    DatabaseService().Search().listen((data) => _inList.add(data));
  }

  final _listController = BehaviorSubject<List<Profile>>();
  Stream<List<Profile>> get outList => _listController.stream;
  Sink<List<Profile>> get _inList => _listController.sink;

  Stream<Profile> nextProfile(String uid) {
    var id = outList
        .map<int>(
            (results) => results.indexWhere((profile) => profile.uid == uid))
        .first;

    Stream<Profile> profile = id.then((index) {
      return outList.map<Profile>((results) => results.elementAt(index));
    });

    return profile;
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listController.close();
  }
}
```

I've tried this code but it's throwing error.

```
A value of type 'Future<Stream<Profile>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Stream<Profile>'.
```

```
  Stream<Profile> nextProfile(String uid) {
    var id = outList
        .map<int>(
            (results) => results.indexWhere((profile) => profile.uid == uid))
        .first;

    Stream<Profile> profile = id.then((index) {
      return outList.map<Profile>((results) => results.elementAt(index));
    });

    return profile;
  }
```

Comment: You need to `await` the call to `id.then`.

Comment: I need to return the item as stream. If I use await I'll need to make the method async which doesn't work with stream.

Comment: Right now `id` is a Future. You have no choice but to either `await` it or come up with a completely different solution.

Comment: There must be a way to achieve this without using Future.

Comment: You are working with streams. Streams are inherently asynchronous structures. As such, calling `first` is an asynchronous action, hence why it returns a future. While there may be ways to circumvent this and get the data synchronously, they are all but guaranteed to be antipatterns and result in fragile, convoluted, and highly coupled solutions. Instead, it's best to question why you need to get this data synchronously in the first place, and whether using streams at all is a good fit for this application.

Comment: Let me explain, basically I have a screen showing list of Firestore document items. 
When you click on an item you go to the details screen and on this screen, you should be able to go bookmark the item and should be able to navigate to previous or next item. I choose stream so that any changes to the document (bookmark) is reflected instantly. For example, if I bookmark an item then go to the next item then go back to it, I should see the item status bookmarked. The list items screen can be future<Profile>.Thank you for taking your time to answer my questions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seems to work. Not sure whether this is the best solution.

```
 Stream<Profile> nextProfile(String uid) {
    var index = outList
        .map<int>(
            (results) => results.indexWhere((profile) => profile.uid == uid))
        .first
        .asStream();

    int nextIndex;
    index.listen((index) {
      nextIndex = index + 1;
    });

    return outList.map<Profile>((results) => results.elementAt(nextIndex));
  }
```